# How to read and store apk metadata in spring boot application

Tags: java, android, spring, apk

We are working on an Android Store. It's a prototype based on Spring for the back end and for the client we use the open source project Aurora : https://gitlab.com/AuroraOSS/AuroraStore

We have to store some information about the apk we upload in our Nexus.
Our first question is how could we read AndroidManifest.xml in our Spring application ? Is there any maven module available ?

The second question is how could we manage Android info in our database ? For example, we have PackageInfo that is typically for Java Android Project, under Android Studio. But we have to store for an app these information? How could we dot it ?

```
package android.content.pm;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.os.Parcelable.Creator;
import androidx.annotation.RecentlyNonNull;

public class PackageInfo implements Parcelable {
    @RecentlyNonNull
    public static final Creator<PackageInfo> CREATOR = null;
    public static final int INSTALL_LOCATION_AUTO = 0;
    public static final int INSTALL_LOCATION_INTERNAL_ONLY = 1;
    public static final int INSTALL_LOCATION_PREFER_EXTERNAL = 2;
    public static final int REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED = 2;
    public ActivityInfo[] activities;
    public ApplicationInfo applicationInfo;
    public int baseRevisionCode;
    public ConfigurationInfo[] configPreferences;
    public FeatureGroupInfo[] featureGroups;
    public long firstInstallTime;
    public int[] gids;
    public int installLocation = 1;
    public InstrumentationInfo[] instrumentation;
    public boolean isApex;
    public long lastUpdateTime;
    public String packageName;
    public PermissionInfo[] permissions;
    public ProviderInfo[] providers;
    public ActivityInfo[] receivers;
    public FeatureInfo[] reqFeatures;
    public String[] requestedPermissions;
    public int[] requestedPermissionsFlags;
    public ServiceInfo[] services;
    public String sharedUserId;
    public int sharedUserLabel;
    /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    public Signature[] signatures;
    public SigningInfo signingInfo;
    public String[] splitNames;
    public int[] splitRevisionCodes;
    /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    public int versionCode;
    public String versionName;

    public PackageInfo() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public long getLongVersionCode() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void setLongVersionCode(long longVersionCode) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public String toString() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int parcelableFlags) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
To read an apk metadata, we found this module :
https://github.com/hsiafan/apk-parser

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.dongliu</groupId>
    <artifactId>apk-parser</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If it worked for you, post it as an answer with more details and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found this plugin https://github.com/hsiafan/apk-parser to parse the information.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.dongliu</groupId>
    <artifactId>apk-parser</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Then with the documentation provided, we retrieve all the information and save in database